# Select All Checkbox Issue in case of one Row

Tags: lightning

[image][image]I have a select all checkbox.its working in all scenario.In case of one row it will not work. how to resolve it?

component:

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="head"><ui:inputCheckbox click="{!c.checkAllCheckboxes}" aura:id="checkbox"/></th>
                                <th class="head">Space Name</th>
                                <th class="head"> Status</th> 
                                <th class="head">No. of Units</th>
                                <th class="head">No. of Units</th>
                                <th class="head">Space Cost/Units</th>
                                <th class="head">Zopa Limit/Desk</th>
                                <th class="head">Price/Units</th>
                                <th class="head">Conference Credits</th> 
                                <th class="head">Printing Credits</th>
                                <th class="head">Booked To (Date)</th>
                                <th class="head">Booked From (Date)</th>
                                <th class="head"> Proposed Price</th>
                                <th class="head"> Zopa Limit</th>
                            </tr>

                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.wrplst}" var="a">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="cell" >
                                        <p> 
                                            <ui:inputCheckbox value="{!a.isSelected}"  aura:id="inputId"/> </p>   
                                    </td> 
                                    <td class="cell" >
                                        <ui:outputText value="{!a.spsRec.Name}"></ui:outputText>       <!-- Space Name-->
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="cell">
                                        <p><ui:outputRichText value="{!a.spsRec.Status__c}">
                                            </ui:outputRichText></p>                                        <!-- No.of UNITS-->
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="cell">
                                        <p><ui:inputText value="{!a.spsRec.No_of_Desks__c}">
                                            </ui:inputText></p>                                    <!-- No.of UNITS-->
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="cell">
                                        <p><ui:inputText value="{!a.NoOfDesks}">
                                            </ui:inputText></p>                                        <!-- No.of UNITS-->
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="cell">
                                        <p><ui:outputText value="{!a.spsRec.Price_Desk__c}">
                                            </ui:outputText>   </p>                                      <!-- Space Cost/Units  -->
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="cell">
                                        <p><ui:outputText value="{!a.spsRec.Zopa_Limit_Desk__c}">
                                            </ui:outputText></p>                                     <!-- Zopa Limit/Desk   -->
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="cell">
                                        <p><ui:inputText value="{!a.Price}" aura:id="pr"/> </p>                                      <!-- Price/Units   -->
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="cell"><p> <ui:inputNumber value="{!a.conference}"></ui:inputNumber>
                                        </p>                                                       <!-- Conference Credits  -->
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="cell">
                                        <p> <ui:inputNumber value="{!a.Printing}"></ui:inputNumber>
                                        </p>                                                     <!--  Printing Credits -->
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="cell">
                                        <p><ui:outputText value="{!a.spsRec.Booked_To_Date__c}"/></p>               <!--    Booked To (Date)    -->
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="cell">
                                        <p><ui:outputText value="{!a.spsRec.Booked_From_Date__c}"/></p>               <!--      Booked From (Date)  -->
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="cell">
                                        <p><ui:outputText value="{!a.NoOfDesks*a.Price}"/></p>               <!--   Proposed Price  -->
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="cell">
                                        <p>  <ui:outputText value="{!a.spsRec.ZOPA_Limit__c}"/> </p>                    <!--    Zopa Limit  -->
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </aura:iteration>
                        </table>
                        <center>
                            <ui:button class="slds-button slds-button--brand btn-lg" label="Save" press="{!c.SaveRecord}"/>
                        </center> 

                    </aura:if>

                    <br/> 
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                        <c:InventoryRedirect />
                    </aura:set>
                </aura:if>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ui:scrollerWrapper>


<div class="slds-grid">
    <div class="slds-col">
        <div class="slds-box slds-box--small slds-theme--shade slds-text-align--bottom">
            <center><h3 class="slds-section-title--divider"></h3> </center>
            <center> 
                <ui:button label="Delete All" press="{!c.DeleteAll}"/>
                <ui:button label="Cancel" press="{!c.CancelAll}"/>
            </center>
             <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
                <tr>
                    <th class="head">Name</th>
                    <th class="head">No of Units</th>
                    <th class="head">Price/Desk</th> 
                    <th class="head">Proposed Price</th>
                    <th class="head">Zopa Limit  </th>
                    <th class="head">Action </th>
                </tr>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.SpaceLine}" var="item" indexVar="indx">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cell" >
                            <p> 

                                <ui:outputText value="{!item.Name}"/>
                            </p>   
                        </td> 
                        <td class="cell" >
                            <p> 
                                <ui:outputText value="{!item.No_of_Desks__c}"/>
                            </p>   
                        </td> 
                        <td class="cell" >
                            <p> 
                                <ui:outputText value="{!item.Price_Unit__c}"/>
                            </p>   
                        </td> 
                        <td class="cell" >
                            <p> 
                                <ui:outputText value="{!(item.Price_Unit__c*item.No_of_Desks__c)}"/>
                            </p>   
                        </td>
                        <td class="cell" >
                            <p> 
                                <ui:outputText value="{!item.ZOPA_Limit__c}"/>
                            </p>   
                        </td>
                        <td class="cell" >
                            <p> 
                                <button type="button" onclick="{!c.DeleteRecord}" id="{!item.Id}" > Delete </button>
                            </p>   
                        </td>  

                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
             </table>
```

javascript side:

```
    checkAllCheckboxes:function(component,event,helper){
    var checkboxes = component.find("inputId");
    var maincheck=component.find("checkbox").get("v.value");
    var ln=checkboxes.length;
    if(maincheck==true ){
        for (var i = 0; i<ln; i++){
            checkboxes[i].set("v.value",true);
        }
    }
    else if(maincheck==false){
        for (var i = 0; i <ln; i++){
            checkboxes[i].set("v.value",false);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When You Use For Multiple List Its Work Good Bcz You Use InputId As List.

When Same Logic You have One Row But Not Work Bcz.
Here InputId Not Become List Its Single InputId..

Replace

```
 if(maincheck==true ){
    for (var i = 0; i<ln; i++){
        checkboxes[i].set("v.value",true);
    }
}
```

To

```
if(maincheck==true ){
     if(ln == 1){
       checkboxes.set("v.value",true);
     }else{
        for (var i = 0; i<ln; i++){
            checkboxes[i].set("v.value",true);
        }
      }
    }
```

Hope This Work

Comment: Thanks @Swapnil Udamale. Problem here is in variable ln iamnot getting any value. I have added the image please check it. So thats the problem here